# wkhtmltopdf enlarges content on server

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating invoices based on an online office environment. On my local server (win7) everything is working as it should. PDF's are generated perfectly with correct measurements etc. but when generating a pdf via the online server (linux) all the content gets enlarged.
The pdf's hold a header, invoice rules and a footer. All of those hold text and a background-image. This causes the content to go beyond the page dimensions.

Here's an image to illustrate what I mean, left the locally generated pdf and to the right the one generated online. (blanked out some fields)
[image]

Thing's I've tried, but with no succes:

- adding the zoom parameter
- adding the dpi parameter
- updating wkhtmltopdf on the server
- setting max sizes in css (i.e. a4 size in mm)

Does anyone know how to make the PDF look the same on the online server? Is there an argument/parameter I'm missing?

Extra info:

- I'm running v0.11.0 rc2 locally and the server is on v0.11.0 rc1. Coulnd't find the rc2 version for linux or mac.
- I'm using the footer, header and zoom arguments when generating, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague fixed the problem this weekend.
He updated wkhtmltopdf but that didnt help.
Then he proceeded to set the max width in pixels and that did the trick. I already had set the max-width and height in mm but had no effect.
This did make the header get positioned wrong, half way accros the page. The fix for this was adding height:0; to it.
The fixes don't make that much sense to me but hey it works :P.

I'm using the following params now:

```
["disable-smart-shrinking"],
["margin-left" => 0],
["margin-right" => 0],
["page-width" => "210mm"],
["page-height" => "297mm"],
["margin-bottom" => 0],
["header-html" => CUSTOM FUNCTION],
["margin-top" => "90mm"],
["header-spacing" => "90"],
["margin-bottom" => "18mm"],
["footer-html" => CUSTOM FUNCTION],
["javascript-delay" => 1000]
```

Comment: max width in pixels? should be set on the body?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is based on the PHP version.

try:

```
 phpinfo();
```

On both servers, and check if the linux server is compatible with the current wkhtmltopdf version.

Comment: Didn't get the chance to check the server's version yet. But my local version is 5.4 and since we are using traits the server has to be the same version or higher.
But I'll check on monday.
We're also updating wkhtmltopdf on the server now via https://gist.github.com/slickplaid/5557321